# Реализация корзины покупателя в интернет магазине на java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, интернет-магазин

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь реализовать корзину.

В мапу сохраняю объекты корзины. После чего если заказ подтверждается все уходит в базу данных.

Столкнулся с проблемой, что если товар добавить в корзину и зайти на сайт с другого компьютера, добавленные товары остаются.

И собственно вопрос, посредством чего лучше реализовать корзину?

в гугле очень мало информации по данному поводу, поэтому подумал, это плохая практика реализовывать интернет магазин или корзину на java?

Вот мой код:

```
@Service("bookStoreService")
public class BookStoreService {
    private Map<Product, Integer> products = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    @Transactional
    public void addProductToBasket(Product product, int count) {
        products.put(product, count);
    }  
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addProduct/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addProduct(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
    Product product = bookService.getProductById(id);
    bookService.addProductToBasket(product, 1);
    return "redirect:/";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index(Model model,Model mode1) {
    model.addAttribute("listProduct",bookService.listPtoduct());
    mode1.addAttribute("productInBasket", bookService.getBasket());
    return "index";
}
```

index.jsp

```
<c:if test="${productInBasket.size()>0}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Название</td>
            <td>Цена</td>
            <td>Кол-во</td>
            <td><a href="/BookStore/clear">Очистить</a></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${productInBasket}" var="qwe">
            <tr>
                <td>${qwe.key.name}</td>
                <td>${qwe.key.price}</td>
                <td>${qwe.value}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    </c:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данную функциональность, вполне возможно реализовать на java. Но делать это нужно при помощи **cookies**. Т.е. сохранять некоторую информацию о пользователе, на стороне клиента. В момент когда он подключается к вашему приложению, вы у него спрашиваете эту информацию. Это может быть любой уникальный идентификатор. С помощью него, затем загружаете данные об этом пользователе, будь то корзина с покупками, история просмотра и пр.
Как это реализовывается в spring, лучше посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-cookievalue)

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал.